# problems In Characters in java

Tags: java

I would make a simple code in java to replace the letter 'z' by letter 'y' >>> here are the code

```
String s= "generalization";
            for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
                if(s.charAt(i)=='z') s.charAt(i)='y';
```

The compiler return to me an error >>> why?

Comment: Your question seems to be incomplete. You can edit it and add the missing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this perhaps:

```
    String s = "Generalization";
    char[] sChars = s.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < sChars.length; i++) {
        if (sChars[i] == 'z') {
            sChars[i] = 'y';
        }
    }
    s = String.copyValueOf(sChars);
    System.out.println(s);
```

Prints out: `Generaliyation`

Or like suggested in another answer, in this sort of cases there is something called `Regular expressions` aka `regex`, with this the same thing is also accomplished by writing:

```
String s = "Generalization";
s = s.replace("z", "y");
System.out.println(s);
```

This also prints out: Generaliyation.

Comment: Tank you very much, sir

Comment: Upvoted for ya. And corrected because replaceAll returns a String you should reassign to s.

Answer (score 2):

`Strings` are immutable. You can use a simple character array and alter the characters at the corresponding indices

Comment: @AhmedRamadan As answered, strings are immutable. You can't just replace a character in a string like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method `replaceAll` of the String class.

```
String s = "generalization";
s = s.replaceAll("[z]", "y");
```

Be careful, the first argument is a regex!

Comment: regex FTW. :) Much easier if you think of it. :)

Comment: I don't understand why the the code should convert to char[], then loop and replace, and then convert back. Wrong solution tagged as correct!

Comment: Maybe if someone is new at coding and tries to do something, maybe help him to do it according the code he posted rather then only suggest an entire different way and maybe point out that in this case using a regex would have been easier.

Comment: Okay. I agree. @ahmed a regex would have been easier in this case

Comment: @AhmedRamadan you just delete all of the code you have written and replace it with those two lines.

Comment: @StefaanNeyts If you read the javadoc about `replaceAll` "Replaces each substring of this string that matches the given regular expression with the given replacement." then a lot of operations are happening there too.

Comment: I have write it as String s = "Generalization";
   
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (s.charAt(i) == 'z') {
            s.replaceAll("z", "y");
        }
    }
    
    System.out.println(s);